# what is alternative for AuthActions.LOAD_USER_TOKEN_FAIL in sparatcus v3.x

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using **AuthActions.LOAD_USER_TOKEN_FAIL**
action for 2.0 but when I migrate to 3.3.0 I am getting error on this as this has been removed.
can you please let me know what is the alternative for this one if I have to track the HTTP error code like v2.0

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard "credentials" authentication.

You could extend the OOTB `AuthService` and overirde the `loginWithCredentials`, keep the same logic but add some additional logic in the `catch` which is called if the login failed.

I you don't want to add the logic there directly you could create your own `LOAD_USER_TOKEN_FAIL` and dispatch it from there. Alternatively, you can use the b[uilt in Event mechanism](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/event-service) to create a new event an observe it elsewhere in the code.